# Worksheet_Change function works on one computer but not another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use the VBA code written here - https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3633-auto-populate-date-in-excel-when-cell-is-updated.html#a1

which i have pasted below:

The code seems to work perfectly on one computer, but on the other, nothing seems to happen when i make any changes in column B. My first thought is that there might be some sort of option disabled but i'm not sure where to look or how to compare settings between the two computers

would be grateful for any help

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
'Updated by Extendoffice 2017/10/12
    Dim xRg As Range, xCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    If (Target.Count = 1) Then
        If (Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B")) Is Nothing) Then _
            Target.Offset(0, -1) = Date
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Set xRg = Application.Intersect(Target.Dependents, Me.Range("B:B"))
        If (Not xRg Is Nothing) Then
            For Each xCell In xRg
                xCell.Offset(0, -1) = Date
            Next
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In the Immediate Window, put `Application.EnableEvents = True` and hit Enter. Note that the use of `On Error Resume Next` here is not good - that just hides potential errors.

Comment: Also, should be `Target.CountLarge = 1` instead of `Target.Count = 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Your solution seemed to fix the initial error and the date did populate on the adjacent cell. Unfortunately, it also raises the error message: "Run Time Error: 1004 - No Cells Were Found" which seems to relate to line 9 of the code. Would you have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: That means `Target` doesn't have any `Dependents`.